# Angular JS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] uncaught error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making weather forecast web app using angular js.
Below is my little piece of code.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

.when('/',{
      templateUrl : 'pages/home.htm',
      controller : 'homeController'
      })

.when('/forecast',{
      templateUrl : 'pages/forecast.htm',
      controller : 'forecastController'
      })

});

myApp.service("cityService", function(){

})


myApp.controller("homeController", ['$scope','cityService', function($scope,cityService){
$scope.city = cityService.city;
$scope.$watch('city', function(){
    cityService.city = $scope.city;
});



}]);


myApp.controller("forecastController", ['$scope','$resource','cityService', function($scope,$resource,cityService){
$scope.city = cityService.city;
$scope.weatherAPI =
    $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",{
    callback : "JSON_CALLBACK" }, {get : {method : "JSONP" }});
//below is line 41
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.city, appid: 9fc927759b42ed332b58471398219df0});
console.log($scope.weatherResult);


}]);
```

I am getting two errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  app.js:41

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]    angular.js:38 .
```

I have added every possible function, but still its getting error..
Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: `appid` looks like a string, but you don't have quotes around it.

Comment: appid is key generated for using weather apis..and i have encoded that in quotes, still same errors

Comment: i hav edited and mentioned line 41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `appid: 9fc927759b42ed332b58471398219df0`

Should be: `appid: '9fc927759b42ed332b58471398219df0'`